# Light/dark mode button only works once

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a button that switchs the mode from light to dark. By default it's light mode, but for some reason, when I switch to dark mode, it works, but it won't switch back to light mode.

Here is the javascript code:

```
const modeButton = document.getElementById('light-dark-btn');

modeButton.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    if(document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255,255,255)'){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(18,18,18)';
        document.body.style.color = 'rgb(255,255,255)';
    }else if((document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(18,18,18)')){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255,255,255)';
        document.body.style.color = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
    }
})
```

I'm trying to make a button that switchs the mode from light to dark.

Comment: Need to use `===` or `==`,not `=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points needs to pay attention:

1. need to use `==` instead of `=` when compare value,the latter one is assign value
2. need to change `rgb(18,18,18)` to `rgb(18, 18, 18)`,which means add white sopace between them,when debug,you will find it

```js
const modeButton = document.getElementById('light-dark-btn');

modeButton.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    let bgColor = document.body.style.backgroundColor
    if(bgColor == 'rgb(255, 255, 255)' || !bgColor){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(18,18,18)';
        document.body.style.color = 'rgb(255,255,255)';
    }else if(bgColor == 'rgb(18, 18, 18)'){
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255,255,255)';
        document.body.style.color = 'rgb(0,0,0)';
    }
})
```

```html
<button id="light-dark-btn">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is that you're using `=` in the if statements instead of `===`. But you're probably going to run in to some other problems with this approach, because the value of `body.style.backgroundColor` won't always exactly match what you set the style to. For example, I can add  `style="background-color: rgb(255,255,255)"` to the body element. But if I run `console.log(document.body.style.backgroundColor)`, I get `rgb(255, 255, 255)`. Notice how it adds spaces between each number.

A more robust approach would be to just toggle a class on the body element, and use css to update the background and text colors.